# Emberjs Sort records

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to sort the records that I'm getting by date in descending order.

```
//model definition
export default DS.Model.extend({
   name: DS.attr('string'),
   date: DS.attr('number')
}
```

I tried `return this.store.findAll('mymodel').sortBy('date')` but no success. I'm using version 2.3.0.

```
//the data
"mymodel" : {
  "-KBJDc1Ccg2kny1Vzn5B" : {
    "date" : 1456350696971,
    "name" : "Jhon"
  },
  "-KBJH_JN6G-AiAVsRfCS" : {
    "date" : 1456349784907,
    "name" : "Peter"
  },
  "-KBK6ZaiI-6o6KPocrSJ" : {
    "date" : 1456348227848,
    "name" : "Paul"
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say "no success", what happened? Can you give examples of what model data you're receiving, and what order you end up with?

Comment: @alisdair I added the data to the question. By no succes I mean the template renders but no data is shown.

Comment: Based on your model, data, and the code snippet, I can't see what's wrong. Does the data render into the template if you remove the `.sortBy('date')` call? If not, then it's probably not to do with sorting, and it's something else that's the problem.

Comment: Without `sortBy('date')` shows the records as expected (not ordered), but I found a way [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/ember/guide.html) `return this.store.query('mymodel', {orderBy: 'date', limitToLast: 1})`. returns only the newest record as I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Lux said, you can't sort your model in your route because is a promise, but you can sort it in your controller,  adding a computed property.

Your `route` will look like this:

```js
model:function(){

     return this.store.findAll('mymodel');

    }
```

And your `controller` will look like this:

```
sortingKey:['date'],
sortedModel:Ember.computed.sort('model', 'sortingKey')
```

**Why the sort in the router?**

Because when model is set in controller the promise is already resolved.

See:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35624736/3998465
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_sort

Answer (score 5):

Returning `this.store.findAll('mymodel').sortBy('date')` can't work because `findAll` returns a PromiseArray!

If you do it in a `model` hook you should do:

```
return this.store.findAll('mymodel').then(results => results.sortBy('date'));
```

And if you do it in a computed property you probably want to reencapsulate it in an PromiseArray:

```
list: Ember.computed({
  get() {
    let promise = this.store.findAll('mymodel').then(results => results.sortBy('date'));
    return DS.PromiseArray.create({promise});
  }
}
```

Comment: `.then()` didn't worked for me in this case. It renders me the template without the data. Maybe a problem with my set-up

Comment: @Lux It's work fine But I want to date in descending order . is there any method or any way to do that ?

Comment: @niteshsingh `this.store.findAll('mymodel').then( results => results.sortBy('date').reverse() );`

Answer (score 2):

I was just hit by this problem really hard, I just wanted to sort result of findAll() , would never expect to be so big issue.

Luckily friend adviced me to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-composable-helpers sort-by helper, so in hbs in each i just switched original taskItems with 
(sort-by "name:asc" taskItems) , and magic was done.